# how to use GL_RGB9_E5 format?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, opengl-4

I am trying to use **GL_RGB9_E5** format with 3D texture. For this I have created simple test to understand the usage of format. Somehow I am not getting what I expect. Following is test program

```
GLuint texture;
const unsigned int depth = 1;
const unsigned int width = 7;
const unsigned int height = 3;

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, texture);
const float color[3] = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };
const rgb9e5 uColor = float3_to_rgb9e5(color);

GLuint * t1 = (GLuint*)malloc(width*height*depth* sizeof(GLuint));
GLuint * t2 = (GLuint*)malloc(width*height*depth* sizeof(GLuint));
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < height; k++)
        {
            t1[index] = uColor.raw;
            index++;
        }

glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0,
    GL_RGB9_E5,
    width, height, depth, 0,
    GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
    (void*)t1);

glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_5_9_9_9_REV, t2);

index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < height; k++)
        {
            rgb9e5 t;
            t.raw = t2[index];
            index++;
        }
```

What I am expecting is what ever **uColor.raw** I am putting in **t1** I get back same raw color in **t2** .

I have taken **float3_to_rgb9e5** method from [Specification for GL_RGB9_E5](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_shared_exponent.txt)
at bottom you can find code.

It would be great If someone can give me example for how to use it correctly or correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
>     GL_RGB,
>     GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
> ```

This means that you are passing 3-channel pixel data, where each channel is a normalized, 32-bit unsigned integer. But that's not what you're actually doing.

You're actually passing 3 channel data, which is packed into a 32-bit unsigned integer, such that the first 5 bits represent a floating-point exponent, followed by 3 sets of 9-bits, each representing the unsigned mantissa of a float. We spell that:

```
GL_RGB,
GL_UNSIGNED_INT_5_9_9_9_REV
```

Comment: ok Thanks . I am was doing that but might be not understanding it. Thanks for explaination